# Error while binding json

Tags: json, angularjs

I am using Angularjs in one of my programme. I am using it to add items to a json array.  Then I save this array to a temporary file. Programme is working fine upto this time. When I try to bind saved json string to table I get error **Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]** Upon searching documentation I found that AngularJS allows duplicate values by syntax "Track by $index" and example is shown to repeat single dimension json.  My question is, how can I control my repeater with id

**HTML Code**

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 5%; text-align: left;">
            Edit
        </th>
        <th style="width: 5%; text-align: left;">
            Dr./Cr.
        </th>
        <th style="width: 25%; text-align: left;">
            G.L. Head
        </th>
        <th style="width: 25%; text-align: left;">
            S.L. Head
        </th>
        <th style="width: 25%; text-align: left;">
            Narration
        </th>
        <th style="width: 18%; text-align: right;">
            Amount
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="TD in TDS track by TD.id">
        <td style="width: 5%; text-align: left;">
            <button class="btn" ng-click="editTD(TD.id)">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>Edit
            </button>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 5%; text-align: left;">
            {{ TD.dbcr }}
        </td>
        <td style="width: 25%; text-align: left;">
            {{ TD.glhead }}
        </td>
        <td style="width: 25%; text-align: left;">
            {{ TD.slhead }}
        </td>
        <td style="width: 25%; text-align: left;">
            {{ TD.narr }}
        </td>
        <td style="width: 18%; text-align: right;">
            {{ TD.amt }}
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**jQuery** Please note that if I remove $scope.$apply(), no error shows up but data is also not shown.

```
$scope.OpenTemp = function () {
    var vFileName = $("#TempList").val();
    $scope.sysmsg = 'Opening voucher from temporary location';
    var to = "../../WHS/OpenTempJV.ashx";
    var options = {
        type: "POST",
        url: to,
        data: { vFile: vFileName },
        error: function () {
            ShowErrorMsg("Error in opening temporary voucher");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != "") {
                //alert(data.d);
                //$scope.sysmsg = 'success';
                $("#divGrid").show();
                $scope.TDS = $scope.TDS.concat(data);
                //$scope.TDS = data;
                //$scope.$apply();
                //CalcAllTotals(data);
            }
            else {
                ShowErrorMsg("Could not retrieve temporary voucher");
            }
        }
    };
    $.ajax(options);
}
```

**JSON String in data**

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "dbcr": "C",
    "glhead": "A B KING PRO EXCERCISER MACHINE AT COST",
    "glid": "3",
    "slhead": "",
    "slid": "0",
    "narr": "dfasdf",
    "amt": "454",
    "$$hashKey": "004"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "dbcr": "C",
    "glhead": "A.C. AT COST",
    "glid": "593",
    "slhead": "",
    "slid": "0",
    "narr": "asdfasdf",
    "amt": "32434",
    "$$hashKey": "006"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "dbcr": "D",
    "glhead": "ADD ON COURSES (BOOKS)",
    "glid": "6",
    "slhead": "",
    "slid": "0",
    "narr": "asdfasdf",
    "amt": "324",
    "$$hashKey": "008"
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "dbcr": "D",
    "glhead": "GROUP INSURANCE SCHEME (STUDENTS)",
    "glid": "270",
    "slhead": "",
    "slid": "0",
    "narr": "adsfasdfadsf",
    "amt": "44324",
    "$$hashKey": "00A"
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "dbcr": "D",
    "glhead": "HRA (TEACHING STAFF)",
    "glid": "357",
    "slhead": "",
    "slid": "0",
    "narr": "asdfadsfasdfds",
    "amt": "11760",
    "$$hashKey": "00C"
},
{
    "id": 6,
    "dbcr": "C",
    "glhead": "EXTENSION CONST. OF ADMN. BLOCK BUILDING",
    "glid": "267",
    "slhead": "",
    "slid": "0",
    "narr": "adfasdfasdf",
    "amt": "23520",
    "$$hashKey": "00E"
}
```

]

**Chrome error stack**

```
 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=TD%20in%20TDS%20track%20by%20TD.id&p1=undefined
at Error (native)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:6:453
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:182:179
at Object.fn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:97:409)
at g.$get.g.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:98:304)
at g.$get.g.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:101:12)
at Object.TDController.options.success (http://localhost:49399/DAV_JV/accounts/transaction/jvAng.js:254:28)
at x.Callbacks.l (http://localhost:49399/DAV_JV/js/jquery.min.js:4:24584)
at Object.x.Callbacks.c.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://localhost:49399/DAV_JV/js/jquery.min.js:4:25405)
at k (http://localhost:49399/DAV_JV/js/jquery.min.js:6:4709)
```

Comment: use `track by item.id`

Comment: post your `html view` also

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/mSqW0am6DODxctYsu5TY?p=preview - Seems to work fine. I have a sneaky suspicion that it may have to do with your JQuery. Where is this line "$scope.TDS = data;" located?

Comment: it is inside the success function of jquery ajax call. the json string I pasted above was taken from chrome debugger for data variable.